# Trouble on AndroidStudio build

Tags: java, android

When I try to run SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic I get that error:

```
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.6 and Gradle 5.1.1.

Possible solution:
 - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 7.2 version and re-import the project
```

So I Upgrade Gradle, it seems to build and when I run the example and then I get that error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':Application:checkDebugManifest' (type 'CheckManifest').
  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckManifest' property 'manifest' has @Input annotation used on property of type 'File'.
    
    Reason: A property of type 'File' annotated with @Input cannot determine how to interpret the file.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Annotate with @InputFile for regular files.
      2. Annotate with @InputDirectory for directories.
      3. If you want to track the path, return File.absolutePath as a String and keep @Input.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#incorrect_use_of_input_annotation for more details about this problem.
```

I work on Ubuntu 20.04